# comletion for function. Only one tap on button

Tags: swift

i am trying to make func completion to use it everywhere. I want to have only one tap on button per second.

i have code like this

```
var isAllowedToExit = true
if isAllowedToExit {
                interactor.exitProfile()
                isAllowedToExit = false
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { [weak self] in
                self?.isAllowedToExit = true
            }
```

it works perfect, but it is a lot of code to use it everywhere
I am trying to do like this

```
func onlyOneTap(completion: () -> ()) {
    var isAvailableToTap: Bool = true
    
    if isAvailableToTap {
        isAvailableToTap = false
        completion()
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        isAvailableToTap = true
    }
}
```

then use it like this

```
 onlyOneTap {
                interactor.exitProfile()
            }
```

but it doesnot even work. how can i fix my code, and do i have some variants to make it global like extension to use everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the button that you want to use function as outlet and use that function

```
  @IBOutlet weak var someButtonOut: UIButton!


func onlyOneTap(buttonInput:UIButton) {
    buttonInput.isEnabled = false
    
    // your completion
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
        buttonInput.isEnabled = true
    }
    
}
```